# Express.js 4: How to access app.locals.<myvar> in routes/index.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want access my own variable, `app.locals.port`, from app.js, inside my routes/index.js file.

**app.js:**

```
app.locals.port = 3001;
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('*', index); // use router in ./routers/index.js
```

**routes/index.js:**

```
var app = require('../app');

console.log('app.locals.port: ' + app.locals.port);
```

Output in my log when running `npm start` --> `nodemon -e css,ejs,js,json,html,pug ./bin/www`:

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
app.locals.port: undefined
```

My current workaround is to use a global:

**app.js**

```
global.port = 3001;
```

**routes/index.js**

```
console.log('global.port: ' + global.port);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the app object through to routes/index.js.

So in your **app.js** file you could have something like:

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.locals.port = 3001

const index = require('./routes/index')(app)

app.use('*', index)

app.listen(app.locals.port, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on ' + app.locals.port)
})
```

and then in **routes/index.js**:

```
const express = require('express')

module.exports = function(app) {

    const router = express.Router() 

    router.get('/', function(req, res) {
        console.log(app.locals.port)
        res.send('Hello from index.js!')
    })

    return router
}
```

The `app` variable in routes/index.js will then be available within the scope of the module.exports function, which can then be passed to other functions within the file.

As you've also mentioned in the comments, the app object is attached to each request, so if you only need access to the app object within the scope of a route, you simplify your code.

**app.js**

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()
app.locals.port = 3001

const index = require('./routes/index')

app.use('*', index)

app.listen(app.locals.port, function() {
    console.log('Server listening on ' + app.locals.port)
})
```

**routes/index.js**

```
const express = require('express')

const router = express.Router() 

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.app.locals.port)
    res.send('Hello from index.js!')
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: i tried in my own app, got this `/Users/pedro/dev/antsirs/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635
    return fn.apply(this, arguments);`, and then from a newly-generated cli express app, `[nodemon] starting node ./bin/www
/Users/pedro/dev/tmp/testexpresscli/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:458
      throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));`

Comment: I re-tried something I thought i'd done already - accessing `app` via the `req` object inside a request/route handler -- that is part of what i am looking for. ideally, i'd like the `app` var/object to be available outside those handlers -- at 'file scope', if you will. 

`router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.app.get('view engine'));
    console.log(req.app.locals.port);`

Comment: @PeterSmith Sorry for the delay in replying. I've updated my answer so it more closely matches the code you gave. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Can this be modified to use module imports instead of commonjs?

Comment: I had the same problem as @PeterSmith but I had just forgotten to add the "return router" at the end of the function in router.index.js (using the first solution)